# Odd Behavior C# vs Python byte ops

Tags: c#, python

Why does C#:

```
byte[] vals = new byte[] {223, 30, 244, 156};
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) {
  result <<= 8;
  result |= vals[i];
}
print("RESULT: " + result);
```

Yield:

```
RESULT: -551619428
```

While Python:

```
vals = array.array('B', [223, 30, 244, 156])
result = 0
for val in vals:
  result <<= 8
  result |= val
print 'RESULT: %s' % result
```

Yields:

```
RESULT: 3743347868
```

While... throwing array values of:

```
[37, 120, 244, 167]
```

at both languages yields:

```
RESULT: 628683943
```

**EDIT: I didn't include this in the original question, but my actual goal was to make Python behave like C# in this case.  Per the answers below I see I need to force the int overflow on the Python side.**

**This seems to work:**

```
import numpy
result = numpy.int32(result)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# `int` is a signed 32-bit integer. The maximum value of `int` is `2147483647` - that's lower than `3743347868`. The operations you perform cause an overflow, resulting in a negative value.

The C# code will give the same results as Python if you change the type of `result` to unsigned int (`uint`) or a 64-bit integer (`long`):

```
byte[] vals = new byte[] {223, 30, 244, 156};
uint result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) {
  result <<= 8;
  result |= vals[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This calculator tells everything.

[image]

The left side is showing the result in int 64(it will show same result when using unsigned int 32). while the right side is using int 32. because the top bit is used for negative it will show different number.

note that all bits are same. thats just difference between signed and unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that C# is using a 32 bit int so 3743347868 is -551619428
An **unsigned int** should make C# behave more like python in this matter.